# Adding web to .net core console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, console-application, kestrel-http-server

I have .`NET core console application`where I start one process. Now I want to add `web page` where I could add results of that process.

this is my `program.cs` class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .PreferHostingUrls(false)
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
                Startup startup = new Startup();
                var serviceProvider = startup.ConfigureServices(services);
                IWindsorContainer container = serviceProvider.GetService<IWindsorContainer>();
                var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
                var cron = configuration[Enums.ExecutionTime];
                var _logger = container.Resolve<IIBLogger>();
                _logger.LogInfo("Started application");
                RunIbit(cron);
            })
            .Build();
    }

    public static void RunIbit(string cron)
    {

    }

    public static async void Execute(string cron)
    {

    }
}
```

and this is my `startup.cs` class

```
public class Startup
{
    IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public static readonly LoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddMvcCore();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);

        return WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(ContainerManager.Container, services);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

However web page is not opened when I run program. And it shows me that the site `localhosdt:5000` cannot be reached. What I am lacking in my program to start it with web interface? From examples I've looked at seemed like it should work fine, so I am not sure what's the problem.

**EDIT:** I managed to start server on web browser, but then I cannot run `Process` method so it either executes process or runs on web, how do I manage to do both?

this is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        RunIbit();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
                .Configure(app =>
                {

                })
            .Build();
        return host;
        //return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        //    .UseKestrel()
        //    .UseConfiguration(config)
        //    .Configure(app =>
        //    {
        //        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        //        Startup startup = new Startup();
        //        var serviceProvider = startup.ConfigureServices(services);
        //        IWindsorContainer container = serviceProvider.GetService<IWindsorContainer>();
        //        var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
        //        var cron = configuration[Enums.ExecutionTime];
        //        var _logger = container.Resolve<IIBLogger>();
        //        _logger.LogInfo("Started application");
        //        RunIbit(cron);
        //    })
        //    .Build();
    }
```

in `Startup.cs`

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
        });

    }
```

I definitely know I don't need `return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");` this line there but that was how I got it on web and I do not know how to change it

Comment: You mean generate HTML and fire another process to open it in browser or what?

Comment: No it has to work on linux server as well, not only locally

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. I'll delete my comments :-)

Comment: At least you don't have any endpoints. I'd reccomend you to create WebApplication instead of console with some template. It'd would be easyer to understand where is the problem. WebApplication you can start in console as well (netcore). Just chose on the buttom of debug you app instead of IIS/IIS express.